# Problema con el emulador de Android Studio

Tags: android

estoy desarrollando una app en el entorno de `Android Studio` pero tengo problemas al momento de utilizar los emuladores propio de la aplicación. Cuando intento ejecutar mi app dicho emulador queda cargando con el símbolo de `Android` y nunca arranca. Lo estoy ejecutando desde una pc con un procesador `AMD Phenom x4 965 de 3.4Ghz` con `8 GB de RAM`.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes [Ejecutar apps en un dispositivo de hardware](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html?hl=es-419), y a mi opinión es mejor que utilizar cualquier emulador. en caso de que tengas esa opción disponible, debes hacer lo siguiente:

**Primero**: Activar depuración USB en tu celular. en caso de no saber cómo, te dejo un[enlace de cómo hacerlo](http://www.jiho.com/es/recuperar-datos/habilitar-usb-depuracion-en-android.html).

**Segundo**: una vez activada la depuración USB en el celular, conéctalo a la PC y deja que reconozca el dispositivo (algunos marcas de celulares te piden un software especial, tal es el caso de samsung y *samsung kyes*, en el ejemplo que te muestro.) Al "*correr*" tu app, te sale una pantalla dónde puedes ver los dispositivos conectados y tus dispositivos virtuales (emuladores de android). ahí deberías de ver tu dispositivo conectado como en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
si no llegase a aparecer, revisa el celular, usualmente te pide autorización para utilizar la depuración USB en la computadora conectada, como en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando intento emular desde mi dispositivo movil, el entorno queda en proceso de ´Installing apk´ y otras veces ni siquiera me reconoce el dispositivo movil.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a la arquitectura de tu computadora si haz notado existen las x86 para procesadores Intel y los ARM que son para Dispositivos Antiguos me parece que tienes que tener habilitado el hyper-v o algo así para permitir la emulación en tu maquina.
Recuerda que se pueden emular en un dispositivo de 64 Bits puedes instalar los APK de 32 Bits, pero no al revés. De igual modo, no puedes instalar un APK compilado para Intel (x86, x64) en un dispositivo ARM, y vice versa, aunque ambos sean de 32 o 64 Bits.
Algo asi pasa con las PC´s no puedes emular un dispositivo de 64 en uno de 32. Consulta bien la información en android, pero a mi asi me pasaba y no podia emular hasta que cambie a uno acorde a la de mi Arquitectura

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tambien para decirlo mas sencillo fijate en la version de android en el Grandel capaz tenga una version no acorde

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).